# Pointers in C++ : How large should an object be to need use of a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Often times I read in literature explaining that one of the use case of C++ pointers is when one has big objects to deal with, but how large should an object be to need a pointer when being manipulated? Is there any guiding principle in this regard?

Comment: Simply, in terms of only size as you consider, since pointer size is normally 4 byte, any object larger than this size cab be deal with pointer.

Comment: That article is probably misleading or not worded properly.  There is no such guideline.  Use pointers/reference for convenience when passing data into routines.  Passing large amounts of data through the stack isn't a good idea.

Comment: @cup How do you determine how large an amount of data you can (or should) pass through the stack? I think that is basically the question here, and there is nothing misleading about the idea.

Comment: It depends on the architecture.  On some architectures, passing too much would blow the stack.  Typically, I'd say as little as possible: that would be the manual optimization which would reduce the amount of data flowing to the callee and make the program run faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think size is the main factor to consider.

Pointers (or references) are a way to designate a single bunch of data (be it an object, a function or a collection of untyped bytes) from different locations.

If you do copies instead of using pointers, you run the risk of having two separate versions of the same data becoming inconsistent with each other. If the two copies are meant to represent a single piece of information, then you will have to do twice the work to make sure they stay consistent.

So in some cases using a pointer to reference even a single byte could be the right thing to do, even though storing copies of the said byte would be more efficient in terms of memory usage.

EDIT: to answer jogojapan remarks, here is my opinion on memory efficiency

I often ran programs through profilers and discovered that an amazing percentage of the CPU power went into various forms of memory-to-memory copies.
I also noticed that the cost of optimizing memory efficiency was often offset by code complexity, for surprisingly little gains.

On the other hand, I spent many hours tracing bugs down to data inconsistencies, some of them requiring sizeable code refactoring to get rid of.

As I see it, memory efficiency should become more of a concern near the end of a project, when profiling reveals where the CPU/memory drain really occurs, while code robustness (especially data flows and data consistency) should be the main factor to consider in the early stages of conception and coding.

Only the bulkiest data types should be dimensionned at the start, if the application is expected to handle considerable amounts of data. In a modern PC, we are talking about hundreds of megabytes, which most applications will never need.

As I designed embedded software 10 or 20 years ago, memory usage was a constant concern. But in environments like a desktop PC where memory requirements are most of the time neglectible compared to the amount of available RAM, focusing on a reliable design seems more of a priority to me.

Comment: Why do people (and the Standard Library) normally use const-references (rather than const-copies) when passing `std::string`? Is that not related to the potential size of these objects?

Comment: Doing copies would not only be memory-inefficient (since most of the strings are more than 4 or 8 bytes long) and time-consuming, but it would also create dozens of copies of the same information. If the user wants to create two diverging versions of the same string, he has to order a copy explicitly. Otherwise, references are used.

Comment: So you are saying that using pointers (or references) is worth it whenever the size of the data is larger than that of a pointer?

Comment: @jogojapan: is this the same idea that you used when commenting on the answer by Fiddling Bits? Sounds logical in one way.

Comment: @Amani I personally think the answer is far more complicated. The number of times copies are made, the size of caches and cache lines, and probably a whole range of other factors will come into play. I personally tend to make copies of objects even when they are three or four times the size of a pointer, but the real answer would be to try different ways and measure the difference ("profiling"). The main point of my comment here is that I am surprised that kuroi neko first states that size wasn't a main factor, but then seems to contradict this statement implicitly in the comment.

Comment: I see no contradiction here. The main point is to decide whether duplicating the information makes sense or not. If multiple copies are meant to represent the same information and each one is modifiable, it is dangerous since all the copies must be kept consistent. In case of const objects, the information cannot change however often the object is duplicated, so size becomes the only factor. In case of general purpose objects like strings, a choice has to be made. The safest one is to make sure the information source remains unique unless the programmers asks for a copy.

Comment: (continued) It happens that in case of strings, this conservative choice is also memory-efficient most of the time. Still memory efficiency is not the decisive factor.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a pointer when you want to refer to the same object at different places. In fact you can even use references for the same but pointers give you the added advantage of being able to refer different objects while references keep referring the same object.

On a second thought maybe you are referring to objects created on freestore using `new` etc and then referring them through pointers. There is no definitive rule for that but in general you can do so when:

- Object being created is too large to be accommodated on stack or
- You want to increase the lifetime of the object beyond the scope etc.

Comment: thanks, but how do you determine the size as too large or not?

Comment: @Amani: Depends on specific settings of stack size.There is no one rule which will suit all and everyone.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such limitation or guideline. You will have to decide it.

Assume class definition below. Size is 100 ints = 400 bytes.

```
class test
{
private:
    int m_nVar[100];
};
```

When you use following function definition(passed by value), copy constructor will get called (even if you don't provide one). So copying of 100 ints will happen which will obviously take some time to finish

```
void passing_to_function(test a);
```

When you change definition of function to reference or pointer, there is no such copying will happen. Just transfer of test* (only pointer size)

```
void passing_to_function(test& a);
```

So you obviously have advantage by passing by ref or passing by ptr than passing by value!

Comment: That's true, but what information does this add that isn't already implicit in the question?